# Nativescript 8 - prevent WebView from opening external apps

Tags: webview, nativescript

I am building a Nativescript 8 Core app that has a WebView where the customer can navigate to different sites.  Can I prevent the WebView from opening an external app when the customer lands on a URL linked to the app?  For example, if the customer clicks on a link to amazon.com/... the device opens the Amazon app automatically.

I understand that if the app (in this case Amazon) has universal links registered, this is the normal behavior from the browser, but is there a way to prevent that from happening inside the WebView?